# Using recursive power function in log function, without Math.functions

Tags: java, math, recursion

like it says in the title I have the problem that I'm required to make my own power and log methodss and use them on my input. 
My power function seems fine until I try to use it in my loga(b) function.
One problem is that I don't understand the for loop in my log method as I copied that one in class to understand it later. Another problem is that I don't know how the built in Math.pow() works, if I had code or pseudocode for that I could guess how my own power function is different.
Thanks in advance and please go easy on me I'm still quite new to all of this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Numbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double i1;
        double i2;
        System.out.print("type your a:");
        i1 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("type your b:");
        i2 = input.nextDouble();
        input.close();
        sumRange(i1, i2);
        power(i1, i2);
        log(i1, i2);
        System.out.println("Sum from a to b: " + sumRange(i1, i2) + "\nFibonacci for A: " + fibonacci(i1)
                + "\nFibonacci for B: " + fibonacci(i2) + "\nA^B:" + power(i1, i2) + "\na%b: " + mod(i1, i2)
                + "\nloga (b)" + log(i1, i2));
    }

    // if I'm honest I don't understand how the log code works exactly,
    // what I do know is that this code calculates the correct log
    // with Math.pow() function
    // My own power function doesn't seem to work and I don't know how the
    // MAth.pow()
    // function is different from mine
    static double log(double i1, double i2) {
        double value = 0;
        for (double i = 1; i > .001; i /= 10) {
            while (!(power(i1, value) > i2)) {
                value += i;
            }
            value -= i;
        }
        return value;
    }

    static double power(double i1, double i2) {
        if (i2 == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (i2 == 1) {
            return i1;
        }
        // The line below seems to cause problems since used in log(double,
        // double) method
        return i1 * power(i1, i2 - 1);
    }
    // I excluded my 3 other methods as they work fine and don't depend on 
    // each other to work
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to mix `double`s and integer literals in your comparisons and arithmetic operations.

Answer (score -1):

Your power method only works for integer `i2`, else the recursion will never terminate.

For non-integer `i2` you could do at least some linear interpolation after the reduction to between `0` and `1`. Which is a bad approximation for large basis values `i1` but better than nothing.

```
    if( 0<=i2 and i2 <=1) return 1+i2*(i1-1);
```

What about negative `i2`?

```
    if( i2 < 0 ) return 1/power(i1,-i2);
```

Google for "libm/exp.c" for professional implementations of the exponential in the `C` standard library, there are different variants, and similarly for "libm/pow.c".